# Magento 2 : Add Custom Field To Order, Invoice, Shipment, Credit Memo

Tags: magento2, invoice, order-email, shipment, creditmemo

I created one custom field in `sales_order` table, field name is `mycstfield`.

I save my value in that field sucessfully when order is placed.

Now, I want to send that field value in following places.

1. Order Email (From Admin)

[image]

2. Inoive Email and Invoice Print (PDF)

[image]

3. Shipment Print

[image]

4. Credit Memo Email and Credit Memo Print (PDF)

[image]

Can Any one have idea about this, How can I do this.

Comment: what does it means "I want to send that field value in following places."?

Comment: means I need to send this customer field value in following places.

Comment: could you explain better what are you meaning as "following places"? do you want a button next send mail and print with your custom field?

Comment: I am tryting to send my custom field "mycstfield" in the PDF & email which is send to customer while we click on above mension places. Now are you getting my point.

Comment: Ok, now it's a bit more clear, last question to understand completely: do you know that both email and pdf has a similar template, with information above the product table, product table, totals. In which position of these do you want insert your custom field?

Comment: The custom field need to show with totals.

Answer (score 4):

I give my answer about order email. Other emails and pdf should works with the same logic.

You have to look at `\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\layout\sales_email_order_items.xml`

where the block with class `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Email\Items` has the template `\vendor\magento\module-sales\view\frontend\templates\order\items.phtml`

In this template the line `<?php echo $block->getChildHtml('order_totals') ?>` calls the block with totals (always defined in `sales_email_order_items.xml`)

```
...
<block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" name="order_totals" template="order/totals.phtml">
...
```

This template starts with

```
<?php foreach ($block->getTotals() as $_code => $_total): ?>
```

where `$block` is a `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals` instance.

Then, to add your custom field to totals, try to write a plugin related to one **public** method of this class, i think you could choose `addTotal()` or `addTotalBefore()`, in this way your custom field will be added to `$this->_totals` array and it will be printed from the foreach loop.